# In PHP, imagepng() accepts a filter parameter. How do these filters affect the function's output?

Tags: php, image, png, gd, gdlib

How do these filters affect the output of [imagepng()](http://php.net/imagepng) in PHP?

- PNG_NO_FILTER
- PNG_FILTER_NONE
- PNG_FILTER_SUB
- PNG_FILTER_UP
- PNG_FILTER_AVG
- PNG_FILTER_PAETH
- PNG_ALL_FILTERS

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php) simply says, "A special PNG filter, used by the imagepng() function" for each of them.

It seems that using PNG_NO_FILTER will reduce the filesize of the output, but other than that, I am unsure as to how it is affected. Any insight would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the PNG Specifications at http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html The purpose of these filters is to prepare the image data for optimum compression.

> With the **None filter**, the scanline is
>   transmitted unmodified; it is only
>   necessary to insert a filter type byte
>   before the data.
>
> The **Sub filter** transmits the
>   difference between each byte and the
>   value of the corresponding byte of the
>   prior pixel.
>
> The **Up filter** is just like the Sub
>   filter except that the pixel
>   immediately above the current pixel,
>   rather than just to its left, is used
>   as the predictor.
>
> The **Average filter** uses the average of
>   the two neighbouring pixels (left and
>   above) to predict the value of a
>   pixel.
>
> The **Paeth filter** computes a simple
>   linear function of the three
>   neighbouring pixels (left, above, upper
>   left), then chooses as predictor the
>   neighboring pixel closest to the
>   computed value. This technique is due
>   to Alan W. Paeth [PAETH].*

Comment: So which one should we use?

Answer (score 4):

From the imagepng() man page linked to the question,

> filters
>
> Allows reducing the PNG file size. It is a bitmask field which may
>    be set to any combination of the PNG_FILTER_XXX constants. 
>    PNG_NO_FILTER > or PNG_ALL_FILTERS may also be used to respectively 
>    disable or activate all filters.

So, to let libpng try the none, sub, and up filters, you'd use

```
PNG_FILTER_NONE|PNG_FILTER_SUB|PNG_FILTER_UP
```

PNG_ALL_FILTERS is just shorthand for

```
PNG_FILTER_NONE|PNG_FILTER_SUB|PNG_FILTER_UP|PNG_FILTER_AVG|PNG_FILTER_PAETH
```

As for which filter to use, it depends upon the image.  Images with 256 or fewer colors generally compress better with PNG_NO_FILTER, while images with many colors (such as photos) generally compress better with PNG_FILTER_SUB or PNG_ALL_FILTERS.  Applications like "optipng" or my "pngcrush" try to optimize the filter selection.  If you're going to use one of those third-party applications for final optimization, you should just use PNG_NO_FILTERS for your working copies, for speed.

Answer (score 2):

Those are all different algorithms the PNG encoder can use to determine pixel values.  Don't know a whole lot, but this page seems to go into some depth: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html