# PNG_ALL_FILTERS, adaptive filtering in php gd

Tags: php, png, filtering, gd

In PHP GD, what does the `PNG_ALL_FILTERS` do and how is that related to "adaptive filtering" of png images?

#### Background

In php, the `imagepng` function from the GD library has a parameter for filters. The [documentation on the filter type constants allowed](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php) only "reveals" that these constants represent:

> A special PNG filter, used by the imagepng() function

Very helpful indeed.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048516/2286722) on SO tells more, but lacks information on the constant `PNG_ALL_FILTERS`. To me, it seems that the other filters are mutually exclusive, so what does "all" do?

In my search, I found that for png filtering, a good strategy (under certain circumstances) would be to pick the most optimal filter *for each scan line separately*, called "adaptive filtering".

Considering the above, I would guess that "adaptive filtering" is accomplished with the `PNG_ALL_FILTERS` option. Am I guessing right? If not, what *does* `PNG_ALL_FILTERS` do? And can I get GD to do adaptive filtering from php?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: From the pngimage description: ".. is a bitmask field which may be set to any combination of the PNG_FILTER_XXX constants. PNG_NO_FILTER or PNG_ALL_FILTERS may also be used to respectively disable or activate all filters." Each line can use any of the filters, but it's "expensive" to *test* them all and select the best option. Presumably, `PNG_ALL_FILTERS` does just that.

Comment: @Jongware: thanks, I've read that too. Still far from a confirmation, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GD uses libpng.

The libpng manpage says essentially what the pngimage description said.  If that's "far from a confirmation" then you'll need to read the libpng source for confirmation.  In libpng's png.h, the macros are defined:

```
/* Flags for png_set_filter() to say which filters to use. */
#define PNG_NO_FILTERS     0x00
#define PNG_FILTER_NONE    0x08
#define PNG_FILTER_SUB     0x10
#define PNG_FILTER_UP      0x20
#define PNG_FILTER_AVG     0x40
#define PNG_FILTER_PAETH   0x80
#define PNG_ALL_FILTERS (PNG_FILTER_NONE | PNG_FILTER_SUB | PNG_FILTER_UP | \
                         PNG_FILTER_AVG | PNG_FILTER_PAETH)
```

The macros are used in png_write_find_filter(), which contains code like this:

```
if (filter_to_do & PNG_FILTER_SUB)
    [calculate figure of merit for the SUB filter]
else if (filter_to_do & PNG_FILTER_UP)
    [calculate figure of merit for the UP filter]
...
else if (filter_to_do & PNG_FILTER_PAETH)
    [calculate figure of merit for the PAETH filter]
```

Then select the filter with the lowest figure of merit for the scanline being written.  The PNG_ALL_FILTERS macro simply provides a short way of enabling all filters for testing.

Comment: A bit late, but: if I understand your answer correctly, then there should be `if`s instead of `else if`s in the second code snippet. Otherwise it would enter **only** the first `if`'s body (calculate figure of merit **only** for the SUB filter and not for the other filters).